# What is the good way to have a multi input field in Redux Form?

Tags: redux-form

In my project we are building a form with `React` and `Redux-Form`. We have a single information that is composed by the value of two inputs. But the values of each input is combined and validated together.

The first implementation try was by connecting each component with `Field`. It let us update the state properly but we couldn't validate all the values together with the `validate` prop.

The second Try was using `Fields`component but it does not have a `validate` prop. We thought in create a Pull Request for it but the API for it isn't clear yet, since what we want to validate the combination of the two values and the behavior of the `Fields` props (such as `parse` and `format`) is different, executing the function for each input inside `Fields` component separately.

I know it is possible to create a component and use `Field` to connect with the application state, but I didn't want to manage things as the touched prop, or the callbacks to update the state, or other things that I even have noticed, since `Redux-Form` has all of it done.

The fact is that I end up with an implementation but it didn't looked very elegant. I'd like you to take a look at the implementation and give your opinion, sugest other solutions and even if this solution is not implemented in `Redux-Form` yet we could maybe open a pull request for that.

Here is an example implementation

Simple form container

```
import SimpleForm from 'app/simpleForm/components/simpleForm'
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'simpleForm'
})(SimpleForm)
```

Simple form component

```
import React from 'react'
import { Field } from 'redux-form'
import MultiInputText from 'app/simpleForm/components/multiInputText'

const onSubmit = values => alert(JSON.stringify(values))

const validateAddress = (value) => {
  if (!value) return 'Address is empty'
  if (!value.street) return 'Street is empty'
  if (!value.number) return 'Number is empty'
  return null
}

const SimpleForm = ({ handleSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(onSubmit) }>
      <Field label="Home Address" name="home" component={MultiInputText} type="text" validate={validateAddress}/>
      <Field label="Work Address" name="work" component={MultiInputText} type="text" validate={validateAddress}/>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default SimpleForm
```

MultiInputText component

```
import React from 'react'
import { Fields, FormSection } from 'redux-form'

const renderAddreessInputs = ({ street, number, error }) => (<div>
  <input {...street.input} type="text" />
  <input {...number.input} type="text" />
  { street.meta.touched && number.meta.touched && error && <span className="error">{error}</span> }
</div>)

const MultiInputText = (props) => {
  const { input: { name }, label, meta: { error }} = props
  const names = [
    'street',
    'number'
  ]

  return (<div>
    <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
    <FormSection name={name}>
      <Fields names={names} component={renderAddreessInputs} error={error}/>
    </FormSection>
  </div>)
}

export default MultiInputText
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1) Use *record-level* validation.

```
reduxForm({
  form: 'addressForm',
  validate: values => {
    const errors = {}
    if(!home) {
      errors.home = 'Address is empty'
    }
    // etc, etc. Could reuse same code for home and work
    return errors
  }
})
```

2) Create a single input that handles a complex value.

```
<Field name="home" component="AddressInput"/>

...

const AddressInput = ({ input, meta }) =>
  <div>
    <input
      name={`${input.name}.street`}
      value={(input.value && input.value.street) || ''}
      onChange={event => input.onChange({
        ...input.value,
        street: event.target.value
      })}/>
      ...other inputs here...
  </div>
```

That's total pseudocode, but I hope it gets the point across: **a single input can edit a whole object structure**.

Personally, I'd choose Option 1, but I prefer record-level validation over field-level validation in general. The nice thing about Option 2 is that a single `AddressInput` could be reused across the application. The downside is that you don't get specific field-level focus/blur/dirty/pristine state.

Hope that helps...?

Comment: Thansks for the answer. I think the option 2 is better for our context. But losing `redux-form` support over the `touched` flag was sad. I could handle it with component state and `touch` action creator.  In the end it gets ok, but if other flags were needed it could get a lot of stuff in the component.